# Add gravity form to all woocommerce products

Tags: woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I am doing a woocommerce shop where I am supposed to add the measurement details to all products. How can I do this?Is the only way to add individually to all products.Is there any method to add a single gravity form to all products?

Comment: [Measurement  Price Calculator](http://www.woothemes.com/products/measurement-price-calculator/) or [Gravity Forms Add-On](http://www.woothemes.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/) might be appropriate.

Comment: I am using gravity forms..I just want to know how to add the form to all products